# simple website interface with PayPal with _xclick

Tags: paypal

ok, it's working.  However, I need one thing fixed:
how to remove the shipping to field for in our case it's not needed.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in no_shipping=1 (if you're using Website Payments Standard).
E.g. `<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">`

For Express Checkout, you'd add `NOSHIPPING=1` in your SetExpressCheckout API call.